# How to continue CSS list on new page?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I was wondering how to continue a list on a new page in CSS.

For example, I have an `<ol>` list with roman numerals. However, the list will be quite big and I decided it would be good to continue the list on a new page.

How can I get the second page to 'start off' at a certain number? For example, the first page has roman numerals all the way to 'X'. How do I get a second page to start off at 'X' and continue from there; I don't want to start from 'I' all over again.

I've already tried doing `seqnum` and put it in the HTML code for the continuing list but it's not working. Is there some specific order I have to put it in or something?

Comment: *`Is there some specific order I have to put it in or something?`* creating some order will not create automagically a nice UI with pagination. Where is your code?

Comment: *`it would be good to continue the list on a new page`* What you mean by saying *"new page"*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<ol>` tag has a `start` attribute that you can use:

```
<ol type="i" start="501">
  <li>Item 501</li>
  <li>Item 502</li>
  <li>Item 503</li>
  <li>Item 504</li>
</ol>
```

You just need to specify the starting number for each page.

---

The `seqnum` attribute that you've referred to is no longer relevant for HTML5, as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol).

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using `"start"` on the `<ol>`, you can also use `"value"` on the `<li>` like this:

```
<ol type="I">
  <li value="4">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using start instead of seqnum
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp

Comment: Ok, I will consider for future answers, sorry :/

Comment: no problem I am just guiding you as I was once guided :-)

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much :)